# How to get Bytestring from FileIO.fromPath in an idiomatic way

Tags: scala, akka-stream

What is an idiomatic way of getting akka Bytestring from FileIO.fromPath in Scala?

Comment: Can you add any more about your use case? ```FileIO.fromPath``` creates a ```Source``` which you can then do a lot of different things with.

Comment: I just want to read a file in memory as ByteString.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the simplest way would be to use `runFold`:

```
FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("some file path"))
  .runFold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _)
```

This returns a `Future[ByteString]`.

That said, it is very likely that just loading the entire file with `Files.readAllBytes` and then converting the resulting `Array[Byte]` into a `ByteString` will be more efficient:

```
ByteString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("some file path")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform bytestrings from `Source` using functions like `map`

```
FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("some file path")).map { byteString => 
  doSomething()
}
```